# How to reject "wrong" inputs in a from in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form linked to a table. One column of the table is "smoker".  I need either a "1" or a "0" in that column. To do this, I created another cloumn as a dummy called "dummysmoker".

The dummysmoker column will be filled in by a user and it's set to assign the corresponding "smoker" column a "1" if a user answers "yes" (and puts yes in the dummysmoker column).

While a "1" is only generated if the user puts "yes" in the dummy column, a "0" is generated in any other case (e.g. "no", "not", "hell, no!", ...).

However, I would like to limit the user to only being able to select "yes" or "no" (maybe through a radio button tag?).

The problem is, I don't know how to include suggested data entries in a radio button tag, I only figured a way to link them to existing table entries.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: You don't need the `dummysmoker` column. You can create a form field, either a select or radio button, that will input 1 or 0 based on the response.

Comment: @BrandonCordell uhm... care to evaluate? I thought my idea was genius :D

Comment: See @uDaY's answer below.

Comment: For UI, two radio buttons or a two-line pop-up can be replaced by a checkbox, which is cleaner but has some implications. See https://www.nngroup.com/articles/checkboxes-vs-radio-buttons/ for more information, and things to consider when designing the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of ways to achieve what you want:

1. You can use radio button or
2. Dropdown select

Using a radio button:

```
<% form_for(@myform) do |f| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :smoker, '1' %> 
  <%= f.label :smoker, 'Yes', :value => '1' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :smoker, '0' %>
  <%= f.label :smoker, 'No', :value => '0' %>
<% end %>
```

Using dropdown:

```
<%= select_tag(:smoker, options_for_select([['Yes', 1], ['No', 0]])) %>
```

Comment: Your radio_button values should be 1 and 0, not yes and no.

Comment: Oops! That's what happens when I have no coffee..Thanks! made the change

Comment: using radio buttons works just fine. i just tried the dropdown option. unfortunately, it doesn't actually generate any database entries. i can't seem to figure out why. suggestions?

Comment: can you show the html output source? if you are doing same like I showed?

Comment: `<%= nann_form.label "Do you have a driver's license?" %><br>
        <%= select_tag(:dln, options_for_select([['Yes', 1], ['No', 0]])) %><br><br>`

so obviously I'm asking for a driver's license ;)

Comment: In that case you would be using a `select` instead of select_tag e.g.,  `<%= nann_form.select(:dln, [['Yes', 1], ['No', 0]]) %>`